# Why can't I connect my Android device to localhost using the Intel XDK app?

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I'm a novice in app development. I'm using the Intel XDK to make an Android app.

The app works by connecting to a database in a backend done with Symfony, and is behaving fine in the emulator. I want to test now from a real device, using my PC as localhost, through WiFi. I read that you have to retrieve the localhost IP address with ipconfig, and then use that IP for the connection. However, when I test the app it doesn't connect. The strange thing is that if I use the mobile browser with the same URL, the connection works: I can see the XML files that I use to fetch the database information.

The code for the connection in the app:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();            
xmlhttp.onerror=transferFailed;
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.xxx.x.x/symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/reportes/reportes.xml",false);
```

The onerror function:

```
function transferFailed(e) {
  alert("Error al conectar:"+e.target.status);
}
```

As I said, the connection doesn't work and I get the alert message: "Error al conectar: 0"

If I put the address `http://192.xxx.x.x/symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/reportes/reportes.xml` in the mobile browser I get the correct XML file.

**Edit:** Well it seems the problem was the sycnhronus request. Later i had to parse the response xml. I dont' know why in the emulator and in an app that i made in phonegap some time ago it worked without parse. The code:

```
function mapIni() {


        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();            
        xmlhttp.onerror=transferFailed;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/symfony/web//app_dev.php/api/v1/reportes/reporte.xml",true);

        xmlhttp.onload= function (event) {
        alert("onload:"+xmlhttp.response);
        };

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {


             xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
             xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
             xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,'text/xml');

             x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");


            alert("x[0]:"+x[0].getElementsByTagName("tipo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be failing because of Cross-Origin request, add this script tag: `<script src="xhr.js></script>"` and try on device. You don't need the actual `xhr.js` file, just add the script tag in `index.html`, the Intel XDK build will include it to workaround the Cross-Origin policy.

Comment: When i add that script the alert message is not showed but it doesn't work either, the data is not loaded :/

Comment: also try adding `<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>` before xhr.js

Comment: I did it like that, but the same thing happened

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues.  Synchronous use of XHR is often a problem if you are expecting the rest of your javascript runtime to be responsive while the network request is executing.
I would first try asynchronous requests (which really should be preferred anyway):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","...",true);
```

You may have to send the request after opening it (this is certainly true for non-GET requests, but maybe GETs work without sending, but I'm suspicious)

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();            
xmlhttp.onerror=transferFailed;
xmlhttp.open("GET","...",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Finally, presumably you have some handler attached to the onload event for when this does work for you :)

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener('onload', function (event) {
  console.log(xmlhttp.response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!. It seems the problem was the synchronous request, but now a i have another problem. I can see the xml content with an alert in the mobile device, but for same reason the getElementsByTagName() method doesn't work. I updated the post to show the code.

Comment: Well the problem is solved, i just had to parse the xml response. I don't know why in the emulator it worked without parse, and the same with a phonegap app that i did some time ago. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, good.  Yes, I often forget that part (or parsing a JSON response with JSON.parse as well).  Glad you found it.  I can't explain why it worked in the emulator, although it is possible that since the emulator intercepts XHRs that it parses the responses intelligently, but I'd be suspicious about that.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, while the simulator is on the same machine and recognizes localhost, your actual Android device cannot interpret where is localhost. For the device build, change localhost to the server name, under windows this the computer name that was assigned when you first installed windows, and test through a browser ensuring that you can access the files via the computer name. Once verified, than change localhost to your computer name. You also have to ensure CORS is permitted and enabled.